# How can I add values to a sequence such that the mean is unaffected?

Tags: average

In order to do some data resampling so I can align certain time series, I need to modify some sets of numbers. I have a sequence of 563 data points, nominally divided into chunks of 30 values. I expected 570 values. I need to average chunks of 30 to get meaningful output. That leaves one unfortunate chunk of 23 values, and the math question arose:

How can I add an arbitrary number of values to a set without altering the average of the set?

Suppose one had the set

$$
X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\ldots x_n\}
$$
which has the average of
$$
\overline{X} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N}x_n
$$
How would I construct the numbers $x_{n+m}$ for arbitrary $m$ to make a new set
$$
X'=\{x_1, x_2, x_3 \ldots x_n, x_{n+1},x_{n+2}\ldots x_{n+m}\}
$$
such that
$$
\overline{X}=\overline{X'}
$$

Comment: Just add any set that has the same average.